# Access HyperLink inside ItemTemplate inside TemplateField ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP TemplateField inside a data populated GridView as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" OnRowDataBound="gvReport_RowDataBound" CssClass="table table-bordered">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" SortExpression="Delete" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "Edit?from=Delete&ID=" + Eval("ID") %>' ImageUrl="Assets/SmallDelete.png" SortExpression="PathToFile" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In other words, at the end of each row, there is a delete 'button'.  I can tell whether a particular row/record has been deleted by checking the true/false value of the BoundField Delete in my code behind as follows:

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      TableCell statusCell = e.Row.Cells[0];

        if (statusCell.Text == "True")
        {
           //change ImageUrl of Hyperlink for this row
        }
     }
```

Right now, my icon is red for delete, but in the case that a record has already been deleted,
I would like to change the image to a different icon (a blue one).

How can I change this ImageUrl if statusCell evaluates to true?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so we will need two parts here:

We need (want) to persist the data table that drives the grid).

The REASON for this?
We kill about 3 birds with one stone.

We use the data table store/save/know the deleted state
We use that delete information to toggle our image
(and thus don't have to store the state in the grid view).

We ALSO then case use that table state to update the database in ONE shot, and thus don't have to code out a bunch of database operations (delete rows). We just send the table back to the database.

In fact in this example, I can add about 7 lines of code, and if  you tab around, edit the data? It ALSO will be sent back to the database. And this means no messy edit templates and all that jazz (which is panful anyway).

Ok, so, here is our grid - just some hotels - and our delete button with image:

markup:

```
    <div style="width:40%;margin-left:20px">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover  borderhide" >
      <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="HotelName" >
            <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="HotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="ORDER BY FirstName" >
            <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="LastName" >
            <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="City" >
            <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="City" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Height="20px" Style="margin-left:10px"
                     ImageUrl="~/Content/cknosel.png" 
                     Width="24px" OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

      </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDeleteAll" runat="server" Text="Delete selected" Width="122px"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete all selected?')" />
    </div>
```

Ok, and the code to load up the grid - NOTE WE persist the data table!!!!!

Code:

```
    DataTable rstTable = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
        else
            rstTable = (DataTable)ViewState["rstTable"];
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        // load up our grid
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName ",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            rstTable.Clear();
            rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            GridView1.DataSource = rstTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        ViewState["rstTable"] = rstTable;
    }
```

Ok, so far, real plain jane. The result is this:

[image]

Ok, so now all we need is to add the delete button click event.

That code looks like this:

```
    protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow rRow = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;
        DataRow OneRow = rstTable.Rows[rRow.DataItemIndex];

        // toggle data
        if (OneRow.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            // undelete
            OneRow.RejectChanges();
            btn.ImageUrl = "/Content/cknosel.png";
        }
        else
        {
            // delete
            OneRow.Delete();
            btn.ImageUrl = "/Content/ckdelete.png";
        }
    }
```

Again, really simple. But NOTE how we use the data table row state (deleted or not).

And this ALSO toggles the image for the delete button.

So, we don't have to care, worry, or store/save the sate in the grid.

So, if I click on a few rows to delete, I now get this:

[image]

So far - very little code!!!

Ok, so now the last part. the overall delete selected button. Well, since that is dangerous - note how I tossed in a OnClientClick event to "confirm the delete. if you hit cancel, then of course the server side event does not run.

But, as noted since we persisted the table? Then we can send the table deletes right back to the server without a loop. The delete code thus looks like this:

```
    protected void cmdDeleteAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // send updates (deletes) back to database.
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID = 0",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter daUpdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder daUpdateBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(daUpdate);
            daUpdate.Update(rstTable);
        }
        LoadGrid();  // refesh display
    }
```

So, note how easy it is to update (delete) from the database. If you look close, I used text boxes for that grid - not labels. The reason of course is that if the user tabs around in the grid (and edits - very much like excel), then I can with a few extra lines of code send those changes back to the database. In fact the above delete button code will be 100% identical here (it will send table changes back with the above code. So, if we add rows, edit rows then the above is NOT really a delete command, but is in fact our save edits/deletes/adds command!